# Remove login tokens for meteor auth

Tags: authentication, meteor

I am not sure if this has been asked before but the `loginTokens` are getting really large and without any cleanup make my database increase in size. What is being done about this? what are others doing to manage this. I am referring to the default `Meteor.users.services` which has an array of loginTokens that get created every time the user logs in/out

```
"resume" : {
        "loginTokens" : [
            {
                "token" : "HMntXepqzPBLDGkGX",
                "when" : 1372559065392
            },
            {
                "token" : "uCHqA95HZZyN5tRtH",
                "when" : 1372563545565
            },
            {
                "token" : "sNGZhhATTrTg8582w",
                "when" : 1372622561176
            },
            {
                "token" : "hPWpm4uQQXWrkK6NS",
                "when" : 1372634411432
            },
            {
                "token" : "DFntTEcsKKT6bJ3rx",
                "when" : 1372635411745
            },
            {
                "token" : "BBM3acLQhuNtsHvkn",
                "when" : 1372638979158
            },
            {
                "token" : "EHgLLHMh6JWxKfuoe",
                "when" : 1372825386462
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This has been referenced several times on the Meteor google group but it's not a high-priority issue. In my authentication system, I delete tokens more than a day old whenever a user logs in. This ensures that the tokens don't expire if they haven't managed to log in for a while.

```
Accounts.registerLoginHandler (loginRequest) ->

  # ... Do whatever you need to do to authenticate the user

  stampedToken = Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken();
  Meteor.users.update userId,
    $push: {'services.resume.loginTokens': stampedToken}

  # Delete old resume tokens so they don't clog up the db
  cutoff = +(new Date) - (24*60*60)*1000
  Meteor.users.update userId, {
    $pull:
      'services.resume.loginTokens':
        when: {$lt: cutoff}
  },
  {multi : true}

  return {
    id: userId,
    token: stampedToken.token
  }
```

Comment: are you overriding the `registerLoginHandler` method in this file https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js///? If so when/where are you doing this (Meteor.startup client/server )

Comment: No, I'm not overriding it, I'm calling it. (This is coffeescript, try http://js2coffee.org to see the equivalent Javascript.) The code snippet above defines a new login handler, so you can pull it into whatever authentication system you are using.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I did file an issue on this and there is a pending pull request that fixes it:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/891

Answer (score 0):

I use Meteor with Vue and I fixed it of the following way:

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt((loginAttempt) => {
if (loginAttempt.allowed && loginAttempt.user.services.resume?.loginTokens?.length > 0) {
    const loginTokensOfUser = loginAttempt.user.services.resume.loginTokens;
        Meteor.users.update(loginAttempt.user._id, {
            $set: {
              'services.resume.loginTokens': [loginTokensOfUser.pop()]
            }
        });
    return true;
}
});
```

This code must be in the server side.
Tested in:
Meteor 1.10.2
Vue 2.6.11