# Remove old login tokens

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a custom login method, but now my database is being clogged with redundant `resume` tokens.

I'm trying to remove them by a cutoff date but I can't seem t get the syntax right:

```
cutoffDate = new Date() - 60 * 1000; // 60 seconds old

Meteor.users.update(
    {_id: userId}, 
    {$pull: {
        'services.resume.loginTokens': {
            when: {$lt: cutoffDate}
        }
    }},
    {multi: true}
);
```

I've referenced this similar issue, but can't seem to get it working: [Remove login tokens for meteor auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457729/remove-login-tokens-for-meteor-auth)

Example of data:

```
"_id" : "hLfYkJaEeFJ9EXxvK",
    "services" : {
        "password" : {
            "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$UhWFGD.YXCxXXtd2.nAG7eo8cTyGxOGQMdCGErxMg73n8TlsYNQ.K"
        },
        "resume" : {
            "loginTokens" : [
                {
                    "when" : ISODate("2015-04-27T00:16:43.836Z"),
                    "hashedToken" : "sHP3xLHCIpTd2qXlIhEKIIxH237rd4fLbWkRqd8cMWs="
                },
                {
                    "when" : ISODate("2015-04-27T00:33:52.501Z"),
                    "hashedToken" : "tB3fBdxRvBNavVl7bJIIGm2FQb8TquhwQnTGvhbLVvk="
                },
                {
                    "when" : ISODate("2015-04-27T00:33:52.504Z"),
                    "hashedToken" : "WVwVv/JpEXaMdnqrFlZ+RM7rYLPafaRHPUFOhhBXgYM="
                }
...... and so on ......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You might want to try updating your users collection on the server. For your use-case a server-side job could clean-up all user accounts on a regular basis.
- Your `cutOffDate` is a `long` and not a `Date` object. Maybe try to compile a date object and use that for the query (that doesn't mean that the `long` query doesn't work, I haven't verified that)

Comment: I was running things server-side of course. I needed a Date object, so I just converted the calculated milliseconds to a new date object.