# Mongodb with node is using high cpu usage on Docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, rocket.chat

Hi I've installed [Rocket.chat](https://rocket.chat) on ubuntu Aws micro instance, It running with Nginx, MongoDB, and node, where MongoDB is running with docker image `mongo:3.0`
It was running smoothly on the day of installation but after some times It server was getting slow, I examined within the server with `top` command. It was MongoDB using cpu% around 70. and the next day It flickers with more than 90%.

I've reinstalled everything on the server but it is same again, no luck.

Here is the screenshot for `top` cmd.
Please let me know if any other stats are needed for this.
[image]

How can I examined the main problem here, how can I optimize it to make it work properly.

Thanks

Comment: This seems more like a Rocket.chat support question than a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to know why this issue arises. I started implementing my custom chat platform with Meteor.
So the cause of the problem was `services.resume.loginTokens` in the user object.
We were trying implementing rocket chat methods/api on the custom native android application.
Whenever application is calling the login method from the android app, It was adding a new login token without deleting the previous ones (for multi-system logins)

so if you'll delete the previous one with some date check, It won't create  overheads to the user object.

```
Accounts.registerLoginHandler (loginRequest) ->

  # ... Do whatever you need to do to authenticate the user

  stampedToken = Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken();
  Meteor.users.update userId,
    $push: {'services.resume.loginTokens': stampedToken}

  # Delete old resume tokens so they don't clog up the db
  cutoff = +(new Date) - (24*60*60)*1000
  Meteor.users.update userId, {
    $pull:
      'services.resume.loginTokens':
        when: {$lt: cutoff}
  },
  {multi : true}

  return {
    id: userId,
    token: stampedToken.token
  }
```

I got this solution from this so [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457729/remove-login-tokens-for-meteor-auth)

Comment: Can I just ask for some clarification:
1: Is this a collection you have designed, call users? Or is it the collection of mongo's own users, for mongo authentication?
2: So the cause of the problem was the existence of a lot of sub-documents in an array, in documents in the users collection. Do you know why this made the server use so much CPU?

Comment: This design and functionality is from rocket.chat, I was implementing its API and methods into my android project.
so If you have logged in, then either you should use existing login token, or logout from the app.

Comment: My app was in development tries, So I was trying logging in manually, without the use of login tokens or logging out.

Comment: From MDG: "Key thing with Meteor is the way DDP sends changes to documents at the level of top-level document fields. What this means is that if you have large and complex subfields on document that change often, DDP can send unnecessary changes over the wire."